# Genymotion GPS is not updating

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, genymotion

I have installed genymotion along with the google play services. I have installed Google Maps using the apps store and i would like it to update my location to either my current location or a fake location i provided. The reason is that i am trying to test an app that uses the google maps api.

Device i created is a Galaxy S6 -6.0.0 - API level 23
Settings > Personal > Location > High Accuracy is on
GPS for the emulator is ON and the location is set. When i go back to my app however, it is not updating the location on the map.

Is there a way to inject the location with geny shell or?

**EDIT** : I can also access my maps app from the browser but I get the following:

1) website wants to know your location? I press share location

2) This site cannot access your location. Change this on the Settings > Advanced > Website screen

There is nothing to do here except clear location preferences for individual sites.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone retrieving getLastKnownLocation on Genymotion in order to set a point on the map or something of the sort like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(
                    AppCompatActivity.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // First try and get last location from network provider
            location  = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            // If that doesn't work, try the GPS provider
            if(location == null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
```

Setting the device lat/lng through the GPS widget or the Genymotion shell does not automatically update your lastKnownLocation the device. I had to manually open Maps, let it update to the specified position in order to set lastKnowLocation, and it worked from there.